# Sort and limit joined table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this `majors` table

| **id** | **name** | **group** | **score** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Computer Science | A | 688 |
| 2 | Electrical Engineering | B | 647 |
| 3 | Psychology | A | 616 |

(more data on the link below)

And this `tests` table

| **id** | **group** | **score** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 690 |
| 2 | A | 650 |
| 3 | C | 600 |

Basically what I want to do is to make a list of the top 5 majors according to the score of the test based on the score of the major and the according group (except `C`, `C` is combination of `A` and `B`), limited to 5, and sorted descending. So the joined table will be

| **test_id** | **group** | **test_score** | **major_name** | **major_score** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 650 | Electrical Engineering | 647 |
| 2 | A | 690 | Computer Science | 688 |
| 2 | A | 690 | Pyschology | 616 |
| 3 | C | 690 | Computer Science | 688 |
| 3 | C | 650 | Electrical Engineering | 647 |
| 3 | C | 690 | Pyschology | 616 |

[Link for the fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kztL1CXC1L7zQ2XKXpiWsq/0)

Is it possible to do this with `JOIN`?

So far I have tried to use the basic `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.group, m.score
FROM majors AS m
JOIN tests AS t ON m.group = t.group
ORDER BY t.score DESC, m.score DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

But sure that is not the right query as it'll limit all the results to 5, not limiting each of the joined data to 5.

Comment: What have your tried?  Why did it fail?  Stackoverflow is not a free SQL writing website ... You should try something, and explain what the problem is. (exception: "_I do not know SQL_" )

Comment: This is a simple cross join , you will feel bad hundreds or more links for that

Comment: @Luuk oops! I forgot to add that. Haven't tried many ways as I have no clue but I've updated my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using  MySQL8+, you would use [ROW_NUMBER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

Using MySQL 5.7:

```
SET @r:=0;
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.group, m.score, @r:=@r+1 as row
FROM majors AS m
JOIN tests AS t ON m.group = t.group
ORDER BY t.score DESC, m.score DESC
-- LIMIT 5
) x
WHERE x.row <=5
ORDER BY x.score DESC
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/AlfcnvMF)

output:

| id | name | group | score | row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Computer Science | A | 688 | 1 |
| 100 | Political Science | B | 671 | 3 |
| 101 | Psychology | A | 651 | 4 |
| 102 | Music | B | 578 | 5 |
| 10 | Physics | B | 532 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to assign a rank to each row within each group, and then filter only the top 5 rows for each group. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT
  t.id AS test_id,
  t.group AS test_group,
  t.score AS test_score,
  m.name AS major_name,
  m.score AS major_score
FROM
  tests AS t
  JOIN majors AS m ON t.group = m.group
WHERE
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM majors AS sub_m
    WHERE sub_m.group = t.group AND sub_m.score > m.score
  ) < 5
ORDER BY
  t.score DESC, m.score DESC;
```